# Creating a sublist of the original list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to make a function that takes two parameters positions to take from list and original list and then copy indexed numbers to a list. Also i included the Struct for the list and the head. I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Error i commented the line.

code:

```
struct node_struct {
    Item item;
    link next;
};

struct list_struct {
    link first;
    int length;    
};

list sublist(list A, list pos_list) {

    int index = 0;
    link tempForindex = malloc(sizeof *tempForindex);
    link temp2 = malloc(sizeof *temp2);
    list finale = malloc(sizeof *finale);
    link temp3 = malloc(sizeof *temp3);
    tempForindex = pos_list->first;
    temp2 = A->first;
    temp3 = finale->first;
    int counter = 0;
    while(tempForindex->next != NULL)
    {
        index = tempForindex->item;//EXC_BAD_ACCESS code1
        counter = 0;
        while(temp2->next != NULL)
        {
            if (counter == index)
            {
                temp3->item = temp2->item;
                temp2 = A->first;
                temp3 = temp3->next;
                break;
            }
            temp2 = temp2->next;
            counter++;
        }
        tempForindex = tempForindex->next;
    }

    return finale;

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I note that you have done 2 terrible things: 1. You don't check the return value of `malloc()`. 2. You `typedef`ed a pointer, that's bad because the reader can have trouble figuring out that it's a pointer, in fact if you don't assign the return value of `malloc()` to it I wouldn't know.

Comment: Your first sentence is unintelligible, so you're asking us to reverse-engineer code (which may be deeply flawed) to determine your intent (which may be grossly misguided) and figure out why your code doesn't achieve it. Or something, I don't know, you haven't actually stated a question.

Comment: `list finale = malloc(sizeof *finale);...temp3 = finale->first;` : `finale->first` is uninitialized. So `temp3->next` is can't this.

Answer (score 0):

It all hopelessly flawed.

You need to get patterns going with linked lists. The structures are fine, but the fact that the code is crashing in the position indicated suggests to me that pos_list has not been set up correctly.

iterate through a list using this pattern

```
list mylist;
link ptr;
for(ptr = mylist->first; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
{
   /* loop body */
}
```

now write a test function to print out both arguments and ascertain that they are valid.